# "android.widget.LinearLayout" cannot be cast to "android.widget.TextView" in the ListView onItemClick

Tags: android, textview, android-listview, toast

I'm trying to put in a `Toast` the selected value from `ListView`.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id){
          // Now you have the id, you can set the background colour.
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),((TextView)v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

The error I get:

```
Error: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `ListView` row layout doesn't contain only a `TextView` you'll get that exception(the `TextView` can't be wrapped with a `LinearLayout` or something else). Instead you could do this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id){
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v;
    TextView t = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_textview);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```